# O identificador do memory nao esta definido

Tags: c++

O script basicamente seria isso.

#include

## pragma comment(lib,"user32.lib")

DWORD WINAPI th(LPVOID param)

{
    while (TRUE) {

```
    if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_F1) & 1)
    {


        Memory mem = new Memory();
        DWORD PID = mem->GetProcessByName("PROCESSO");

        bool bypassed = false;
        bool IsAttach = false;



        for (;;)
        {
            if (mem->GetProcessByName("PROCESSO") == 0)
            {
                IsAttach = true;
                exit(0);
            }
            if (!bypassed)
            {
                if (mem->GetModuleBase32("MODULO DO PROCESSO", PID) > 0)
                {
                    Sleep(1000);


                    mem->FindPattern32("PROCESSO", 0x00000000, 0x00000000, (BYTE)"\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00", 5);
                    WriteProcessMemory(OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, false, PID), (LPVOID)mem->Result32[0], (PBYTE)"\x00\x00\x00", 3, 0);


                    mem->Free();

                    mem->FindPattern32("PROCESSO", 0x00000000, 0x00000000, (BYTE*)"\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00", 9);
                    WriteProcessMemory(OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, false, PID), (LPVOID)(mem->Result32[1] - 14), (LPVOID)"\x00", 1, NULL);

                    bypassed = true;

                    IsAttach = true;
                }
            }
            if (bypassed)
            {
            }
        }
        Sleep(100);
    }
```

}
    return 1;
    }

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hModule,
    DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
    LPVOID lpReserved
)
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        CreateThread(NULL, NULL, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)th, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        break;
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

```
return(TRUE);
```

}

Esta dando esse erro

> "o identificador "Memory" nao esta definido".

Nao sei se esqueci de importar alguma coisa ou se estou fazendo alguma coisa errada..

Comment: E você colocou o `include` necessário? Na hora de compilar especificou que a biblioteca deve ser incluía? Se não fez isso sugiro começar por coisas mais simples antes partir para coisas mais complexas.

Comment: coloque o seu código inteiro para nos termos uma melhor definição do que esta acontecendo

Comment: Coloquei o código inteiro agora